# How to add attributes in template which is not a field contact (Sendinblue)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mailchimp, sendinblue

I can't figure out how to add attributs in template email with sendinblue and springboot.

I tried this:

```java
Contact sendEmailContact = new Contact(user.getFirstname(), user.getLastname());
sendEmailContact.setSUBSCRIBENAME(user.getFirstname() + " " + user.getLastname());
emailController.sendEmail(api.getId(),api.getRegisterUserTemplateId(), user.getEmail(), sendEmailContact);
```

but **SUBSCRIBENAME is not a field in my contact in sendinblue**?

How to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the specifics of your langage client, but Sendinblue template can take two sources of information.

1. from the contact stored in your contact list. In the template it looks like contact.FIRST_NAME, for example

   2. from params sent by your app. In the template it looks like params.SUBSCRIBENAME for example

=> so I would suggest looking in the docs for sending email params in Java